# unable to execute "put" in the function of map using hbase and hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

everybody.I'm using mr to process some log file, the file is on hdfs. I want to retrieve some info form the file and store them to hbase.

so I launch the job

```
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`${HBASE_HOME}/bin/hbase classpath` ${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/hadoop jar crm_hbase-1.0.jar /datastream/music/useraction/2014-11-30/music_useraction_20141130-230003072+0800.24576015364769354.00018022.lzo
```

if I just run job as "hadoop jar xxxx" it shows "not find HbaseConfiguraion"

My code is quite simple,

```
  public int run(String[] strings) throws Exception {


    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();  

    String  kerbConfPrincipal = "ndir@HADOOP.HZ.NETEASE.COM";
    String  kerbKeytab = "/srv/zwj/ndir.keytab";



    UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(kerbConfPrincipal, kerbKeytab);
    UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser();

    System.out.println(" auth: " + ugi.getAuthenticationMethod());
    System.out.println(" name: " + ugi.getUserName());
    System.out.println(" using keytab:" + ugi.isFromKeytab());

    HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(config);

    //set job name
    Job job = new Job(config, "Import from file ");
    job.setJarByClass(LogRun.class);
    //set map class
    job.setMapperClass(LogMapper.class);

    //set output format and output table name
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TableOutputFormat.class);
    job.getConfiguration().set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, "crm_data");
    job.setOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Put.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
    TableMapReduceUtil.addDependencyJars(job);
```

but when i try to run this MR, I cannot execute "context.write(null,put)"， it seems the "map" halts at this line. 
I think it has relationship with "kerbKeytab", does it mean I need to "login" when I run the "map" process

Comment: The problem could be with "context.write(null,put)" as well, check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198752/advantages-of-using-nullwritable-in-hadoop

Comment: Job job = new Job(config, "Import from file ");
        job.setJarByClass(LogRun.class);
        //set map class
        job.setMapperClass(LogMapper.class);

        TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(table, null, job);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
        TableMapReduceUtil.addDependencyJars(job);   
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job,input);
        //FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(strings[0]));
        int ret = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after adding TableMapReduceUtil it works

```
    Job job = new Job(config, "Import from file ");
    job.setJarByClass(LogRun.class);
    //set map class
    job.setMapperClass(LogMapper.class);

    TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(table, null, job);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
    TableMapReduceUtil.addDependencyJars(job);   
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job,input);
    //FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(strings[0]));
    int ret = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
```